# Reuse NUnit's IConstraint in validation

Tags: c#, validation, nunit

NUnit has an IConstraint interface ([documentation here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.4) and [code here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-framework/blob/5d9a9b2d3ae49892b60f31849d698865d17cbad0/src/framework/Constraints/IConstraint.cs)). It seems to me that reusing this type in my core project for validation purposes makes sense.

Are there unforseen side effects I have not yet recognized? Would you reuse the IConstraint type in your core project? why/why not?

Answer (score 0):

This is more an opinion-based question. Beside that, there are two issues that come to my mind.

Firstly, you can write something like `Assert.That(foo, Is.EqualTo(bar))`, which internally invokes an `EqualConstraint`. To have your custom constraint to be usable like this, you have to "overload" `Is`, so you can have `Assert.That(foo, Is.AsGoodAs(bar))` (where `AsGoodAs` is your custom constraint invocation). See [NUnit's Custom Constraints documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=customConstraints&r=2.6.3) for details. With this you will have two classes with the name `Is` (yours and the NUnit one) and you will also call the default static methods like `EqualTo` via a derived type. Resharper will warn you about this.

Secondly, writing *intelligent* assertion failure texts (like `expected "this", but was "that"`) can be a bit tricky to figure out. You will certainly spend some time on this until you get what you want. Of course this depends on your personal feelings about *nice* texts.